# requests.delete provokes a GET instead of DELETE on artifactory

Tags: python-2.7, tomcat, artifactory

So, I'm trying to clean up my artifactory which runs on tomcat.
I've written a script that give me what I want.
However, when I do a requests.delete() and look in the access logs, I see a GET request for the used URL, and nothing is deleted.

Code:

```
import requests


username="admin"
password="SomeSecurePassword"


r = requests.delete('http://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/my/path/to/delete/0.1.62', auth = (username, password))
```

Log:

> 10.10.5.200 - - [07/Apr/2017:16:44:28 +0200] "GET /artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/my/path/to/delete/0.1.62
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 579

I suspect either a tomcat or an artifactory configuration has to be changed, but I don't know where to start looking.
Google didn't turn anything up off the bat for either artifactory or Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [delete item](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) REST API is using the following request format:

```
DELETE http://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/my/path/to/delete/0.1.62
```

Please note you do not need `/api/storage` as part of request URL.

Comment: which I thought I did by using requests.delete instead of requests.get. What did I do wrong compared to your response?

Comment: please note you do not need /api/storage as part of request URL

Comment: thank you, please edit your answer to clearly denote it there as well